# Finding average by grouping row values pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by

```
data=df.groupby('Term')['Subject'].apply(tuple)
```

I wrote this line in python but I didn't achieved desired output. Can anyone help me out.

I tried many grouping methods but I never came up with the output.

Comment: What is the average for a column like 'Subject'?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at the average of the `Subject` column grouped by `Term`, you were actually quite close:

```py
df.groupby('Term')['Subject'].mean()
```